# OpenGL transformations (glScale, glTranslate, etc)

Tags: opengl, scale, transformation, translate

I'm learning about openGL and how to do transformations such as translating and scaling. I know you have to usually translate to the origin, then do whatever you want (lets say scale), then translate back. From my understanding this is done manually but you can do the same thing with glScale().

My question is do I still need to translate to the origin and back if I use the glScale function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You probably don't need to do any translation to the origin and back, just do the transformations in the required order. Remember that the last transformation applied takes place in the transformed space of the previous ones. For example:

```
// draw object centred on (1,2,3) and ten times bigger
glTranslatef(1,2,3);
glScalef(10,10,10);
drawObject();
```

versus

```
// draw object centred on (10,20,30) and ten times bigger
glScalef(10,10,10);
glTranslatef(1,2,3);
drawObject();
```

In the second example, both the translation and the object are scaled x10, because they're done after the scale. (This scheme allows drawObject() to include transformations and still behave like a single unit.)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot that helps. So basically I just need to do my transformations in order i.e: translate -> scale -> rotate I believe, but I don't have to translate to the origin and back because it seems that the gl functions do that for you.

Comment: No they don't do that for you, but often it doesn't matter. There is no definite rule here: You need to understand what's going on. E.g. if you wanted to have a planet orbiting a sun, you'd do the rotation first, then the translation. The direction of the translation would be rotated by the previous rotation, just as you'd want. But for the daily rotation of the planet itself, you'd want another rotation *after* the translation. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: In the first example we scale then translate, in the second we translate to 1,2,3 and then scale, how does that draw the object in 10,20,30?

Comment: The translation is scaled in addition to the object.

Answer (score 3):

All `glScale` does is multiply the current matrix by a scale matrix. So yes, for what it sounds like you want to do, you would want to apply the scale matrix before applying a translation.

See also [glScale reference](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glScale.xml).

Answer (score 3):

You have to think of the transformations taking place on a stack. In other words, the last transformation you specify takes place first. So,

```
glTranslatef(1,2,3);
glScalef(10,10,10);
glRotatef(45,1,0,0);
drawObject();
```

will first rotate 45 degrees about the x axis, then scale the object to (10,10,10), then translate to (1,2,3). However, you also have to remember that any transformation you apply affects transformations further down the line. If we reverse the order of the above transformations, the rotation will then rotate about a different point.